# Vue, re-ordering list when selecting rendered checkbox behaves funky

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have got an issue I can't get my head around, I have tried to reproduce the error below, however the below code works just fine!

So below is what is supposed to happen.

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
    <middleman :items="items" :selected="selected" @update="update"></middleman>
</div>

<script type="text/x-template" id="checkbox">
    <label :for="$vnode.key">
        {{ value }}
        <input type="checkbox"
               :value="value"
               :id="$vnode.key"
               @change="$emit('update', $event)"
               :checked="isSelected(value)">
    </label>
</script>

<script type="text/x-template" id="middleman">
    <div>
        <checkbox v-for="(item, index) in filtered"
                  :selected="selected"
                  :value="item.value"
                  @update="$emit('update', $event)"
                  :key="`checkbox-${index}`"></checkbox>
    </div>
</script>

<script>
    Vue.component('checkbox', {
        props: ['value', 'selected'],
        template: '#checkbox',
        methods: {
            isSelected(value) {
                return this.selected.indexOf(value) > -1;
            }
        }
    })
    Vue.component('middleman', {
        props: ['items', 'selected'],
        template: '#middleman',
        computed: {
            filtered() {
                return [...this.items].sort((a, b) => this.selected.includes(b.value) - this.selected.includes(a.value))
            }
        }
    })

    new Vue({
        el: '#app',
        data: {
            items: [
                {value: 'BMW', count: 1},
                {value: 'AUDI', count: 1},
                {value: 'VAUXHALL', count: 1},
                {value: 'FIAT', count: 1},
                {value: 'HONDA', count: 1},
                {value: 'LANDROVER', count: 1},
            ],
            selected: ['AUDI', 'HONDA']
        },
        methods: {
            update(event) {
                if (event.target.checked) {
                    this.selected.push(event.target.value);
                    return;
                }
                const index = this.selected.indexOf(event.target.value);
                this.selected.splice(index, 1);
            }
        }
    });
</script>

<style>
    label {
        display: block;
    }
</style>
```

The above is pretty much what I have got. There is a root component, a middleman, and then the checkbox...

However mine is doing this:
[image]

Here is the code, very similar but using single file components:

```js
// Root.vue

<template>
    <div class="app-search">
        <div class="app-search__facets">

            <facet v-for="(facet, key) in facets"
                   @update="updateFacet(...$event, key)"
                   :facet="facet"
                   :label="key"
                   :data="items[key]"
                   :key="key"/>
        </div>
   </div>
</template>
<script>
    import facet from '../Facets/Facet';

    export default {
        components: {
            facet
        },
        data: function () {
            return {
                facets: {
                    manufacturer: [{"control": "checkbox", "type": "value", "size": 20, "selected": []}]
                },
                items: {
                    manufacturer: [
                        {value: 'BMW', count: 1},
                        {value: 'AUDI', count: 1},
                        {value: 'VAUXHALL', count: 1},
                        {value: 'FIAT', count: 1},
                        {value: 'HONDA', count: 1},
                        {value: 'LANDROVER', count: 1}
                    ]
                }
            }
        },
        methods: {
            updateFacet(action, value, facet) {
                switch (action) {
                    case 'add':
                        this.facets[facet].selected.push(value);
                        break;
                    case 'remove':
                        let index = this.facets[facet].selected.indexOf(value);
                        this.facets[facet].selected.splice(index, 1);
                        break;
                }
            },
        }
    }
</script>
```

```js
// Facet.vue

<template>
    <div class="app-search__facet">
        <p class="app-search__facet--title">{{ label }} ({{ selected }})</p>
        <component :is="facet.control"
                   v-for="(value, index) in filter"
                   :data="value"
                   :value="facet.selected"
                   :key="`facet-${label}-${index}`"
                   @value="update($event)" />
    </div>
</template>
<script>
import '@/prototypes/toPascalCase'
export default {
    props: {
        data: {
            required: true,
            type: Array
        },
        facet: {
            required: true,
            type: Object
        },
        label: {
            required: true,
            type: String
        }
    }
    computed: {
        selected() {
            return this.facet.selected.length
        },
        filter() {
            const selected = this.facet.selected;
            return [...this.data].sort((a, b) => selected.includes(b.value)  - selected.includes(a.value));
        }
    },
    methods: {
        component(control) {
            return () => import(`./Controls/${control.toPascalCase()}`)
        },
        update(event) {
            switch(this.facet.control) {
                case 'checkbox':
                    const value = event.target.value;
                    if (event.target.checked && this.facet.selected.indexOf(value) === -1) {
                        this.$emit('update', [ 'add', value ])
                        break;
                    }
                    this.$emit('update', [ 'remove', value ])
                    break;
                default:
                    console.log('Can\'t handle this facet');
                    break;
            }
        },
    },
}
</script>
```

```js
// Checkbox.vue

<template>
    <label :for="$vnode.key" class="app-search__checkbox">
        {{ data.value }} ({{ data.count }})
        <input type="checkbox"
               :id="$vnode.key"
               :value="data.value"
               @change="$emit('value', $event)"
               :checked="isSelected">
    </label>
</template>
<script>
export default {
    props: {
        data: {
            required: true,
            type: Object
        },
        value: {
            required: true
        }
    },
    computed: {
        isSelected() {
            return this.value.indexOf(this.data.value) > -1;
        }
    }
}
</script>
```

Anyone got any idea what is going on here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is caused by the combination of using `v-for` `index` to create a `:key` and sorting items after each select/deselect action. Do not use `index` in `key` - use something unique for each item, for example `item.value`

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.6.14/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
    <middleman :items="items" :selected="selected" @update="update"></middleman>
</div>

<script type="text/x-template" id="checkbox">
    <label :for="$vnode.key">
        {{ value }}
        <input type="checkbox"
               :value="value"
               :id="$vnode.key"
               @change="$emit('update', $event)"
               :checked="isSelected(value)">
    </label>
</script>

<script type="text/x-template" id="middleman">
    <div>
        <checkbox v-for="(item, index) in filtered"
                  :selected="selected"
                  :value="item.value"
                  @update="$emit('update', $event)"
                  :key="item.value"></checkbox>
    </div>
</script>

<script>
    Vue.component('checkbox', {
        props: ['value', 'selected'],
        template: '#checkbox',
        methods: {
            isSelected(value) {
                return this.selected.indexOf(value) > -1;
            }
        }
    })
    Vue.component('middleman', {
        props: ['items', 'selected'],
        template: '#middleman',
        computed: {
            filtered() {
                return [...this.items].sort((a, b) => this.selected.includes(b.value) - this.selected.includes(a.value))
            }
        }
    })

    new Vue({
        el: '#app',
        data: {
            items: [
                {value: 'BMW', count: 1},
                {value: 'AUDI', count: 1},
                {value: 'VAUXHALL', count: 1},
                {value: 'FIAT', count: 1},
                {value: 'HONDA', count: 1},
                {value: 'LANDROVER', count: 1},
            ],
            selected: ['AUDI', 'HONDA']
        },
        methods: {
            update(event) {
                if (event.target.checked) {
                    this.selected.push(event.target.value);
                    return;
                }
                const index = this.selected.indexOf(event.target.value);
                this.selected.splice(index, 1);
            }
        }
    });
</script>

<style>
    label {
        display: block;
    }
</style>
```